# How are machine learning models loaded in an app?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm just getting into Machine Learning and I've been looking at TensorFlow. So let's say I'm building a desktop app that uses TensorFlow and a trained model. I don't understand how you would eventually bundle the application. Would you somehow save the state of the trained model and include it in the app or would all users have to re-train the model themselves when they first start the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an awesome article about this by HBO: [How HBO’s Silicon Valley built “Not Hotdog” with mobile TensorFlow, Keras & React Native](https://medium.com/@timanglade/how-hbos-silicon-valley-built-not-hotdog-with-mobile-tensorflow-keras-react-native-ef03260747f3). It delves quite deep into the details, though.

Machine learning models (like neural networks) are defined by their structure and their parameters/weights. The structure is hard-coded by you, the weights are learned in training. If you have both, you can recreate the model anywhere and run your predictions or whatever it is you're doing.

Let's call the apps that your users will run "clients". No, clients do not have to relearn the model, unless you specifically want them to. Training is an expensive process that takes a large dataset, memory and processing power. A lot of the cool models you see in action, like the one used on FaceApp or other apps, may take weeks of training on a huge cluster to complete. Not to mention that their dataset is probably many many gigabytes in size.

For a lot of the Deep Learning models, even the learned weights themselves might be too large, and/or the processing power needed to even do a single forward pass will be too much for a mobile phone or laptop to handle. That's why many ML apps don't actually ship the model with their app, but rather let the model run on a server. The client then simply sends an input and receives the output a few seconds later. That way you save yourself some trouble, but lose offline capabilities and pay quite a bit for hosting.

So let's forget about hosting the model for a second and assume you have a small, lightweight model that you want to ship with your app. The simplest way would be to store the weights in a file and then pack it with your app. But of course there are many libraries and tools to help you out there. For a TF example, check out TensorFlow mobile: https://www.tensorflow.org/mobile/.